# Error dd_in_ear_load_EXC_ al desplegar ear en websphere

Tags: java, servidor, websphere, war

Tengo un EAR que contiene un WAR de una aplicación web hecha con jdk1.8.0_101 y testeado en un servidor apache-tomcat-7.0.81. Usa servlet 3.0.

Creo el ear con la sig estructura:

```
-multiSubidas.ear
     -lib
         -librerías jar...
     -META-INF
         -application.xml
         -MANIFEST.MF
     -multiSubida.war
```

Pero al desplegar el websphere me marca el siguiente error:

```
AppDeploymentException: [null] org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.exception.DeploymentDescriptorLoadException: dd_in_ear_load_EXC_
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La versión del WebSphere en la que trato de instalar es:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No he podido encontrar mucho sobre ese error en internet, por lo que espero lo que lo resuelva sea la exp de alguien. Alguna idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema fue que la versión del WAS no tiene disponibilidad para servlets 3.0

Primero habría que ver cuál es el error completo, por lo que consulté el archivo SystemErr.log del Websphere el cuál está en

```
Root Installation\IBM\WebSphere\${TuServidor}\profiles\${TuServidor}\logs\server1.
```

El error completo de este caso fue:`

```
[26/09/17 12:23:07:784 CDT] 0000002f SystemErr     R AppDeploymentException: [null]
org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.exception.DeploymentDescriptorLoadException: dd_in_ear_load_EXC_
[26/09/17 12:23:07:784 CDT] 0000002f SystemErr     R org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.exception.DeploymentDescriptorLoadException: dd_in_ear_load_EXC_
Stack trace of nested exception:
org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.exception.DeploymentDescriptorLoadException: WEB-INF/web.xml
Stack trace of nested exception:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Parent Translator (GenericTranslator(servlet,1026440494)) did not find a Child Translator for "multipart-config".
```

Indagando un poco me encuentro con que "multipart-config" hace referencia a un error de versiones con servlets. Yo en mi aplicación usé Servlets 3.0 y trataba de instalarlo en un WAS6.1. La página de IBM nos provee la siguiente información:

[image: Versiones de Websphere]

La cuál nos dice que para usar servlets 3.0 necesitamos mínimo la versión 8.0 del Websphere

Degraciadamente en mi caso no quedó más que hacer un downgrade a mi código y adaptarme a las especificaciones que hay para desarrollar para websphere 6.1